# Facebook SDK FBGraphUser can't store local copy

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've started Facebook integration for a project and I've run into a problem. I am attempting to store the logged in user as a local object so the information can be referenced later, but I can't seem to hold onto the information.

Here is my function for fetching the user data:

```
 if(_session.isOpen)
 {
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState state,
                                                      NSError *error)
     {

         [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                    NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
                                                    NSError *error)
          {
            if(!error)
            {
                NSLog(@"Username: %@",user.name);

                [_user initWithDictionary:user];
                NSLog(@"Username: %@",[_user objectForKey:@"name"]);

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't get user details!");

            }

          }];
     }];

}//endif
```

In this case, the NLog gives "Username: (null)"

I'm pretty new to both ObjC and Facebook so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, I tried to create a member variable :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *loggedInUser;
```

and previously my code for storing the user was

```
if(!error)
            {
                NSLog(@"Username: %@",user.name);

                _user = user;
                NSLog(@"Username: %@", _user.name);

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Couldn't get user details!");

            }
```

Since neither of these worked (the second worked insofar as the second NSLog gave the correct variable, but later attempts to access it outside this function caused a crash) I can only assume I am not storing the information correctly.

Can someone give me some pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to print `user.username` not `user.name`

Comment: I am getting null when trying to access user.username